# Issues with overriding another class

Tags: java, encoding

I'm getting this error for some reason when I try to make a new `withdraw` method for the class "CheckingAccount." I also have a class named Account that has its own withdraw method.

Here's the code:

```
    class CheckingAccount extends Account {
    double overdraftmax = -50;
    
    public CheckingAccount(int id, double balance) {
    }
    public void withdraw(double money) {
            if (this.getBalance() - money >= overdraftmax) {
                withdraw(money);
    }
  }
}

class Account {
    private int id = 0;
    private double balance = 0;
    private double annualInterestRate = 0;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;
    
    
    Account() {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }
    
    Account(int newId,double newBalance) {
        this();
        id = newId;
        balance = newBalance;
        
    }
    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    double getAnnualInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }
    void setId(int newId) {
        id = newId;
    }
    void setBalance(double newBalance) {
        balance = newBalance;
    }
    void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
        annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
    }
    String getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated.toString();
    }   
    double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
            return (annualInterestRate / 100) / 12;
    }
    double getMonthlyInterest() {
            return balance * getMonthlyInterestRate();
    }
    double withdraw(double money) {
            return balance -= money;
    }
    double deposit(double money) {
            return balance += money;
    }
}
```

And here are the two errors I'm getting.

> The return type is incompatible with Account.withdraw(double)
>
> overrides Account.withdraw

I'm not sure what to fix.

Comment: So, what is unclear in the error message?

Comment: You override a method returning a `double` with another one returning `void`, it's not allowed. Either make the superclass return `void` (makes more sense IMHO), or return a `double` value in the overriding method

Comment: @AlexSavitsky this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when overring a method , u need to keep the same prototype of the method in the parent . 
so here  you are mixing the return type .

```
class CheckingAccount extends Account {
        double overdraftmax = -50;

        public CheckingAccount(int id, double balance) {
        }
        public double withdraw(double money) {
                if (this.getBalance() - money >= overdraftmax) {
                    withdraw(money);
        }
      return "double var";
  }
}


class Account {
    private int id = 0;
    private double balance = 0;
    private double annualInterestRate = 0;
    private java.util.Date dateCreated;


    Account() {
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }

    Account(int newId,double newBalance) {
        this();
        id = newId;
        balance = newBalance;

    }
    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    double getAnnualInterestRate() {
        return annualInterestRate;
    }
    void setId(int newId) {
        id = newId;
    }
    void setBalance(double newBalance) {
        balance = newBalance;
    }
    void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
        annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
    }
    String getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated.toString();
    }   
    double getMonthlyInterestRate() {
            return (annualInterestRate / 100) / 12;
    }
    double getMonthlyInterest() {
            return balance * getMonthlyInterestRate();
    }
    double withdraw(double money) {
            return balance -= money;
    }
    double deposit(double money) {
            return balance += money;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Account` class you make method `withdraw()` with returning type `double`, but in class `CheckingAccount` you overriding this method with returning type `void`.

In *Java* you can't change returning type in overriding method, because compiler don't understand what method you want to use.